# how tu run several bash scripts in one line without &&

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have 3 bash scripts and i want to run at time in one single line

Example: 1.sh, 2,sh, 3.sh

```
sudo /etc/init.d/{1,2,3}.sh
```

But doesn't work. And crontab doesn't accept this format

**Note**: I don't want to use:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/1.sh && sudo /etc/init.d/2.sh && sudo /etc/init.d/3.sh
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eval "sudo "/etc/init.d/{1,2,3}.sh";"
```

or

```
for i in {1..3}; do sudo /etc/init.d/${i}.sh; done
```

Comment: thanks. both works. But you must correct the line. Is {1,2,3} not {1..3}. But you don't mention how to add to crontab

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
sudo sh -c "/etc/init.d/{1,2,3}.sh"
```

Comment: Doesn't work. sh: 1: /etc/init.d/{1,2,3}.sh: not found (and the scripts there in path)

Answer (score 1):

Its not entirely clear why you don't want to use "&&", but if its because of the reliance on each one returning an OK exit, you could use ";" instead

You can also use sudo to launch  a shell with "-c" to pass the arguments at the command line, so each script can be run with only 1 invocation of sudo.

```
sudo /bin/bash -c "/path/to/script1; /path/to/script2; /path/to/script3"
```

Comment: thanks but too long. Is the same that sudo /etc/init.d/1.sh && sudo /etc/init.d/2.sh && sudo /etc/init.d/3.sh

Comment: It is long, but it is very different in technical ways - specifically the "&&" means conditional execution on the success of the previous command, while ; acts as a seperator much like enter.   My variant also only only escalates privileges once, unlike sudo which does so 3 times (but, of-course, my variant is at the expense of launching a shell).